# Are the full bridge rectifier on a IGBT pack switching, fast or Schottky diodes?

Tags: diodes, switching, igbt, schottky, motordriver

In a skiip24nab126 IGBT pack for motor VVF drives: are the 3 phase full bridge rectifier diodes fast Schottky or switching or just normal / common diodes like 1N4007? Does the rectifier need to switch fast if its input is 50/60 Hz? Are the freewheeling diodes of the IGBT fast diodes and the same type of the bridge rectifier because they need to be or because it’s easier to build them all with the same technology?

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: The above datasheet says “CAL technology diode”, which is “controlled axial lifetime”. They also provide a white paper: https://www.semikron-danfoss.com/dl/service-support/downloads/download/semikron-technical-explanation-cal-diodes-en-2014-10-16-rev-00/

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet for the SKiiP 24NAB126V1](https://www.semikron-danfoss.com/dl/service-support/downloads/download/semikron-datasheet-skiip-24nab126v1-25230070.pdf) shows that the free-wheeling diodes are of a soft-recovery type using Controlled Axial Lifetime (CAL) technology. Image from the data sheet.[image]

The word "soft" refers to the shape of the reverse recovery as shown in this [image from All About Circuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/fast-ultrafast-soft-standard-schottky-selecting-the-right-rectifier/)

[image]

The datasheet goes on to specify the free-wheeling diodes and the rectifier diodes.
in both tabular data and charts.

[image]

[image]

The following table from the same All About Circuits link shows:

1. That none of the diodes are Schottky diodes.
2. The rectifiers appear to be standard silicon diodes.
3. The free-wheeling diodes are medium fast soft recovery diodes as  mentioned in the datasheet.

[image]